# jquery .animate a display in switch mode whith the ? characteres

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, accessibility

I need to do a transition animation on a block, and I need my block to move and `display:none` at first click and to move back and `display:block` on second click.

I use this for the move effect:

```
$('#bthplus').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $('#plushome');

    $lefty
    .animate({
       right: parseInt($lefty.css('right'),10) == 0 ?
  -$lefty.outerWidth() :
  0 

});
```

which works perfectly. For accessibility, I need to `display:none` the block `#plushome` when is not on my view

I have tried this:

```
  $('#bthplus').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $('#plushome');

    $lefty
    .animate({
       right: parseInt($lefty.css('right'),10) == 0 ?
  -$lefty.outerWidth() :
  0 

})
    .animate({
    display: $lefty.css('display') == "none" ?
  $lefty.css('display'):
  "block"
});
  });
```

the block is still moving, but nothing happened to the display. Does someone have any idea why?

---

### Update

I have read that the display can't be called in this animate fonction and that just the opacity can be called, but that does not solve my problem, beacause a hidden ellement is stil visible for a screen reader, so I presume I need to use the `show()` and `hide()` functions, but how can I have the same testing:

```
  if( $lefty.css("display") == "none" ){

     $lefty.show();
}else{
$lefty.hide();
};
```

---

Update

Ok so my last edit worked, and found the answer myself. I still have a little bug:

new code is

```
 $('#bthplus').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $('#plushome');

    $lefty
    .animate({
       right: parseInt($lefty.css('right'),10) == 0 ?
  -$lefty.outerWidth() :
  0 

});
 if( $lefty.css("display") == "none" ){

 $lefty.show();

}else{

  $lefty.hide();
};
  });
```

and because my element is `display:none` at start, but with the good placement (`right:0`) he was hidden when he was in place and `display:block`  when he was off the screen. I will try to fix this :)

Comment: Translation of "MAJ" (Mise à Jour in french) is "update"

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with the [visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

This should work for you:

```
function _toggleLefty() {
    var _isVisible = $lefty.is(":visible");
    var _right = parseInt( $lefty.css('right'), 10 );
    // Show element to do animation
    if (!_isVisible) {
        $lefty.css({
            "display": "block",
            "opacity": 0
        });
    }
    // Do animation
    $lefty.animate({
        "opacity": _isVisible ? "0" : "1",
        "right": _isVisible ? "-"+$lefty.outerWidth()+"px" : 0
    });
    // Element is visible so we hide it after animation
    if (_isVisible) {
        // We promise this action after it's complete (could use complete option too)
        $lefty.promise().done(function(){
            $lefty.css("display", "none");
        });
    }
}
```

You can't use animate to change the display to none but you can fake it.

Your code had a few minor issues:

- `-$lefty.outerWidth()` won't work, you have to do it as: `"-"+$lefty.outerWidth()`
- You need to change the integers to px: `"-"+$lefty.outerWidth()+"px" : 0)`

Now you can call `_toggleLefty();` to do the animation.

You may also want to check to make sure _right is not `NAN` (not a number)

To explain this a bit:

The part `// Show element to do animation` is allowing the element to be visible but keeps the opacity at 0 so the user won't see it. This allows you to fake the animation for display none as this is then animating the opacity and the right movement.

The last part where I check `if (_isVisible)` is the exit where we force display to none once the animation has completed.

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y7JxT/3/)

Keep note that you don't need to worry about `_right` I left that there in-case you wanted to use it but it can easily work off visibility.

Updated the demo to duplicate your effect.